# jQuery check checkbox is not working with second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have html with anchors and checkboxs. Now When user select to anchor, I want to check checkbox to closest anchor.

For example, If I click to `Travel` anchor Travel checkbox need to be checked and then I click to `Kids` anchor Kids checkbox need to be checked and add/remove `active` class from anchor.

In my example it is working with only first anchor selection, when you select any other anchor it will not work and not select any checkbox.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zaarwejy/1/

```
<div class="row instagram-details">
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Sports</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Health &amp; Fitness</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Photography</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Entertainment</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Food</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Travel</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Lifestyle</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Automotive</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Fashion</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Beauty</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Youth</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Technology</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Weddings</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Adventure</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Luxury</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Tattoos</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Provocative</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Pets</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Kids</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Architecture</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class=""><input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Art &amp; Design</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(".instagram-details a").click(function () {
    var ele = $(this).closest('a').find(':checkbox');
    if ($(':checked').length) {
        ele.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        ele.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of that, you can just use `<label>`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      $(this).closest("label").addClass("active");
    else
      $(this).closest("label").removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
label.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row instagram-details">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Sports</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Health &amp; Fitness</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Photography</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Entertainment</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Food</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Travel</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Lifestyle</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Automotive</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Fashion</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Beauty</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="active">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Youth</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Technology</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Weddings</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Adventure</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Luxury</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Tattoos</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Provocative</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Pets</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Kids</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Architecture</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Art &amp; Design</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlexChar In this case it doesn't matter, you can also use `~`, you've seen the demo, http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zaarwejy/5/, but I agree, `+` is better

Comment: @Tushar True in this case doesn't matter but is preferable(for me at least) to go with `+`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `$(':checked').length` will return a truthy value if any one of the checkboxes in the page is checked

You can simplify the logic using toggling like

```
$(".instagram-details a").click(function () {        
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('active'));
});
```

Here we first toggle the active class of the clicked anchor element, then we sets the checked state of the checkbox using whether the anchor element has the active class or not

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a11Lfkf8/)

Comment: You can literally do the same in one line `$(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).toggleClass('active').hasClass('active'));`. Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/a11Lfkf8/2/)

Comment: Feel free to add the code in your answer, if you think that'll improve the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Change only this:

```
 if ($(':checked').length) {
```

With this

```
 if (ele.prop("checked")) {
```

And it works

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zaarwejy/2

Answer (score 2):

There's no need of using JS, if you can restructure the HTML. You can use sibling selector and `:checked` property of the checkbox to change the styles of the corresponding label.

You can use `label`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zaarwejy/5/)

```css
:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row instagram-details">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="1">Sports</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="2">Health &amp; Fitness</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="3">Photography</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="4">Entertainment</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="5" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="5">Food</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="6" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="6">Travel</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="7" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="7">Lifestyle</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="8" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="8">Automotive</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="9" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="9">Fashion</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="10" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">
    <label for="10">Beauty</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you cannot change the HTML structure, then you need to use JS.

Your selector `$(':checked').length` checks if there is atleast one checked checkbox. So, when one checkbox is checked for next checkbox the code doesn't work.

To toggle the checkbox state use

```
ele.prop('checked', !ele.checked);
```

To toggle class use

```
$(this).toggleClass('active', ele.is(':checked'));
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zaarwejy/3/)

```js
$(".instagram-details a").click(function() {
  var ele = $(this).closest('a').find(':checkbox');

  ele.prop('checked', !ele.checked);
  $(this).toggleClass('active', ele.is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row instagram-details">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Sports</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Health &amp; Fitness</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Photography</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Entertainment</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Food</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Travel</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Lifestyle</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Automotive</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Fashion</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Beauty</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Youth</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Technology</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Weddings</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Adventure</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Luxury</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Tattoos</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Provocative</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Pets</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Kids</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Architecture</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="" class="industrie_branch_option" value="">Art &amp; Design</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this!

```
$(".instagram-details a").click(function () {
    var ele = $(this).closest('a').find(':checkbox');
    if ($(ele).prop('checked')) {
        ele.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        ele.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with following

```
$(".instagram-details a").click(function () {
    var ele = $(this).closest('a').find(':checkbox');

    if (ele.prop('checked')) {
        ele.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        ele.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```